# preprocessing tweets, remove @ and # , eliminate stop words and remove user from list of list in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

i wrote the code below but now I want to p reprocess, so I transformed to lower, I wrote some word to eliminate stop words but it does not work, and I want to remove @ and # and also remove user , can you help me?

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/tweets_en.txt'
wget.download(url, 'tweets_en.txt')
tweets = [line.strip() for line in open('tweets_en.txt', encoding='utf8')]

import spacy
from collections import Counter
# your code here
import itertools
nlp = spacy.load('en')

#Creates a list of lists of tokens
tokens = [[token.text for token in nlp(sentence)] for sentence in tweets[:200]]
print(tokens)


#to lower
token_l=[[w.lower() for w in line] for line in tokens]
token_l[:1]

#remove #

#remove stop word

#remove user

#remove @

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# filtered_words = [[w for w in line] for line in tokens if w not in # stopwords.words('english')]
```

Comment: `"#string".replace("#","")`

Comment: sorry i am new to python, how should i use this line of code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do text pre-processing using spaCy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605946/how-to-do-text-pre-processing-using-spacy)

Comment: thanks , I have searched alot, but the problem is , I have list of list and I dont now how to apply those code to list of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to organise your code into functions: they are reusable, readable, and loopable.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import spacy, re

nlp = spacy.load('en')

stop_words = [w.lower() for w in stopwords.words()]

def sanitize(input_string):
    """ Sanitize one string """

    # normalize to lowercase 
    string = input_string.lower()

    # spacy tokenizer 
    string_split = [token.text for token in nlp(string)]

    # in case the string is empty 
    if not string_split:
        return '' 

    # remove user 
    # assuming user is the first word and contains an @
    if '@' in string_split[0]:
        del string_split[0]

    # join back to string 
    string = ' '.join(string_split)

    #remove # and @
    for punc in '@#':
       string = string.replace(punc, '')

    # remove 't.co/' links
    string = re.sub(r't.co\/[^\s]+', '', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    # removing stop words 
    string = ' '.join([w for w in string.split() if w not in stop_words])

    return string 


list = ['@Jeff_Atwood Thank you for #stackoverflow', 'All hail @Joel_Spolsky t.co/Gsb7V1oVLU #stackoverflow' ]

list_sanitized = [sanitize(string) for string in list]
```

Ouput:

```
['thank stackoverflow', 'hail joel_spolsky stackoverflow']
```

Comment: thanks alot but NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: yes your code is alright but I want to apply to list of list (as I have list of list) and I dont really know to to iterate inside my list of ist, can you help me on my code?

Comment: for example when I do this : for punc in '@#':

[[[w.lower() for w in line] for line in tokens].replace(punc, '')]     I get error, the problem is iteration inside list of list

Comment: Placed the code in a function so you can loop over all strings in your list.

Comment: im very sorry .. but my data  is a list inside anther list (list of list ), like [['thank stackoverflow'], 'hail stackoverflow']

Comment: No, you create a list of list. Your data is a list of sentences (or tweets). I would sanitize the sentences first than split the results in token lists.

Comment: Updated with spacy tokenization.

Comment: every thing is alright , but I also wanted o remove the user  like @cosmetic_candy, when we remove @ (the purpose of removing @ was , remove mentioned people, but it does not remove users , it just remove @ from users, and the last result shows us , users but without @, do you know how do this? I mean remove users, im really sorry, if you dont know I will accept your answer and will ask in anther question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215123/discussion-between-eli-and-sy-ker).